# Plugin error: kotlin-idea.jar contains invalid plugin descriptor

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, plugins

One day I oppened android studio and this poped out as "plugin error":

```
Plugin error: File '~\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2\plugins\Kotlin\lib\kotlin-idea.jar' contains invalid plugin descriptor
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the newest version of Kotlin from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/versions/stable)

then replace the Kotlin file in this directory with the one you downloaded "C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2\plugins"

Answer (score 14):

I went to Menu `Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates` in Android Studio. The dialog shows message `A new Version 212-1.7.10-release-333-AS5457.46 is availible` and an Update Button below the message. After Update and Restart the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted the file in that path. It seems everything worked normally afterward. (You may need to tick the "show hidden files, folder, or drives" from File Explorer Options if you can't find it directly)

Comment: I deleted the file and then I could install the plugin again via `Tools > Kotlin > Configute Kotlin Plugin Updates`. Everything seems fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the newest plugin "Kotlin" from jetbrains site and error disappeared
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/versions/stable